# Где (можно ли) опубликовать статью (не вопрос) на stackoverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Хочу поделиться статьей (серией статей) как пересобрать правильную OS на основе Android Open Source Project. То есть не задать вопросы, а выложить статью для обсуждения. На каких сайтах это можно сделать?

Comment: Хабр? . . . . .

Comment: Ок, понятно. А среди многочисленных сайтов StackOverFlow есть что-то похожее на Хабр? Может что-то англоязычное?

Comment: Задайте вопрос и сами на него дайте ответ.

Comment: @becouse боюсь, такой вопрос получится слишком общий

Comment: хабр англоязычен нынче

Comment: @andreymal, вопрос может быть конкретным, а вот ответ в виде статьи. Максимум что грозит, ... сильно заминусуют

Comment: Задайте несколько вопросов и сами дайте на них ответ. Отметьте вопросы как связанные. @andreymal FYI

Comment: @teran Что за бред? Хабр русскоязычный сайт.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica https://habr.com/ru/company/habr/blog/435764/

Comment: @teran и? Большая часть контента всё ещё на русском. И так будет всегда.

Comment: что и? изначально был дан ответ - хабр. автор спросил про английский - опять хабр. Кто-то еще усомнился что хабр есть на английском, приведена ссылка. В чем у вас-то еще вопрос? Никто не утверждал что он люто популярен в иностранном сегменте. не вижу тут предмета для дискуссии.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica хабр англоязычный сайт не какого отношения к русскоязычию а также русскоразличия  там нету. _Там есть такая проблема что люди которые там пишут страдают от того что не живут именно там где они существуют (ака "западный мир")_

Comment: @teran "хабр англоязычен нынче" для меня прозвучало так, будто он теперь чисто англоязычный, поэтому и переспросил)